# How to put a verbatim text above a matplotlib pdfpages figures?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have a python code that generates five matplotlib figures put together into a single PDF file using the pdfpages backend. I write some python strings on top of page 1. In addition, I now wish to add some seven-eight lines describing the parameters and assumptions as a verbatim text on page 1. This text resides in a text file which I want to put on this page. Please suggest how to proceed?

Comment: What's wrong with formating in TexWorks/TexStudio/Kile or any other latex editor, plotting graphs as .pdf and including them in your file? Matplotlib is a graphing module, not exactly a full latex service. PyPDF might be what you're looking for in combination with mpl.